# HTML: Error: Start tag a seen but an element of the same type was already open

Tags: html, href

I have this problem when I tried to validate my code:

```
Error: Start tag a seen but an element of the same type was already open.
```

I changed the sentence a couple of times but nothing seems to work and frankly I don't understand the error.

Error: Start tag a seen but an element of the same type was already open.
From line 134, column 52; to line 134, column 84
e taking: `<a href="https://www.drugs.com/">Medica`

Here is the part of my code that went wrong

```
<p>
    Resources: To learn more about diabetes and living with diabetes:
    <a href="http://www.diabetes.org/?referrer=https://www.google.com/">
        American    Diabetes Association><br>
        To learn more about the drugs that you are taking: 
    <a href="https://www.drugs.com/">
        Medications
    </a> 
    <a href="#top">
        Back to top of page
    </a>
</p>
```

Comment: You should copy and paste the portion of the HTML where the validator flags an error

Comment: Solved! nevermind!

Comment: this means you are opening an `a` without closing  an `a` first

Comment: Can you delete this post please?

Comment: try to learn yourself to order your code so that its easy to read, common mistakes are easily not found in un-ordered code.

Answer (score 0):

You have three `<a>` start tags and only two `</a>` end tags. You need to add the missing end tag.

Answer (score 0):

This part is invalid:

```
<a        href="http://www.diabetes.org/?referrer=https://www.google.com/">
American    Diabetes Association>
```

You need to close it like this:

```
<a        href="http://www.diabetes.org/?referrer=https://www.google.com/">
American    Diabetes Association</a>
```